# UIPickerView values

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want UIPicker to start from 2 (0, 1 to be not displayed)

```
self.tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    for(int x = 2; x < 10; x++)
    {
        [self.tmpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
    }

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [self.tmpArray count];
}
```

With the code above UIPicker shows 0,1,2,3 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not in any way passing on the values from tmpArray, so they have no bearing on what UIPickerView displays.

You need to implement viewForRow:forComponent: and be able to supply suitable views when the picker view requests them.